# Transforming DataFrame to get the count of records for a given hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

[image]

Where `Time request submitted` is a timestamp. `date` and `hour`
 are the values extracted from `Time request submitted` as extra columns.

I would like to transform it to something like this:

[image]

Where row represents the date and the columns are hours: 9AM, 10AM and so on. I would like the values to be the counts for the given hour for a given day instead of 0s. Hope it make sense.

I was playing a bit with `groupby`, `resample` and `pivot_table` but I can't seem to be able to achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: I think you should know post pic as input data and expected output is hard for us to answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know. I will do better next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['date'], df['hour'])
```

Alternatives:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='hour', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

df1 = df.groupby(['date', 'hour']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Or:

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Time request submitted'].rename('date'), 
                  df['Time request submitted'].rename('hour'))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for adding alternatives, I can see what was missing on my solutions.